# Override toString() in java

Tags: java, tostring

Why toString() works? We didn't call it. It works like a constructor.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        A a=new A();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
class A{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

what about we will delete `println`, make breakpoint and run the program in debug mode?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a=new A();
        A a2=a;

    }
}
class A{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

as we can see, "Hello" sets to `a` and `a2`.
Why??

Comment: Please post in English.

Comment: why toString() works? We didn't call it.
it works like a constructor

Comment: We can't actually see, you can attach screenshot of the debugger, so your question will be more clear for everyone.

Comment: Because toString() is defined on the object and it is then used when you call println to get a string representing the object and in the debugger it is used to display the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're debuging code in Java (and many other languages), the IDE evaluates expressions using built-in methods of the same language. The default representation of the object for IDE usually the string representation.

The debugger calls `toString` method to obtain something to show in variables and since you've overiden it, the debugger shows you `Hello` instead default description of the object (which is the default implementation of `toString` in the class `Object`).

According the [`java.lang.Object` source code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Object-source.html), the implementation:

```
 177:   /**
 178:    * Convert this Object to a human-readable String.
 179:    * There are no limits placed on how long this String
 180:    * should be or what it should contain.  We suggest you
 181:    * make it as intuitive as possible to be able to place
 182:    * it into {@link java.io.PrintStream#println() System.out.println()}
 183:    * and such.
 184:    *
 185:    * <p>It is typical, but not required, to ensure that this method
 186:    * never completes abruptly with a {@link RuntimeException}.
 187:    *
 188:    * <p>This method will be called when performing string
 189:    * concatenation with this object.  If the result is
 190:    * <code>null</code>, string concatenation will instead
 191:    * use <code>"null"</code>.
 192:    *
 193:    * <p>The default implementation returns
 194:    * <code>getClass().getName() + "@" +
 195:    *      Integer.toHexString(hashCode())</code>.
 196:    *
 197:    * @return the String representing this Object, which may be null
 198:    * @throws OutOfMemoryError The default implementation creates a new
 199:    *         String object, therefore it must allocate memory
 200:    * @see #getClass()
 201:    * @see #hashCode()
 202:    * @see Class#getName()
 203:    * @see Integer#toHexString(int)
 204:    */
 205:   public String toString()
 206:   {
 207:     return getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
 208:   }
```

Comment: You mean toString() is always colled when any program starts?

Comment: No. Allways when you're debugging it (viewing the particular variable in debugger) or printing the object, or trying implicitly convert it to string in any other way